# Issue with correctly displaying a USB Camera input to winforms picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, webcam

I have a USB videocamera that spits out 640x480 image data frames that I'd like to put in a winforms pictureBox. When I map the data onto the pictureBox using SetPixel the image looks fine, but SetPixel is crushingly slow, so I tried this instead:

```
    void CreateBitmap()
    {
        int width = bitmap.Width;
        int height = bitmap.Height;
        int n = 0;

        // copy normalized data into 1D array
        lock (imageDataLocker)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
                {
                    Color c = Colorizer.GetColor(imageData[i, j]);
                    rgbValues[n] = c.R;
                    rgbValues[n + 1] = c.G;
                    rgbValues[n + 2] = c.B;
                    n += 3;
                }
            }
        }

        // Copy image data into the bitmap
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
        IntPtr ptr = bitmapData.Scan0;
        int bytes = rgbValues.Length;
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
    }
```

Where rgbValues is a 1D byte array containing 3 bytes per pixel, imageData is a 2D int array supplied by the camera, and bitmap has a 24bppRgb format. I don't get any errors with this, but when I assign the bitmap to the BackgroundImage of my pictureBox there is a strange banding effect:

[image: WEbcam]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure that one pixel coded by 3 bytes?

Comment: the image should be that of the webcam

Comment: gabba: according to this page, yes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719797(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Maybe in output bitmap another representation?

Comment: Have you tried with different webcam input pictures? Is the result always the same? Could you post an input picture so that we can compare the expected result to the actual result?

Comment: @ColinDocherty I know, but WHAT is the image you expect to see.  Paste in the question one image as it should be and one as it is.  It tells a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think your outer loop should be j=0; j

I tested this with this simple pattern which makes a bitmap with the left half blue and the right half black.

```
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(16, 16, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        BitmapData bitmapData = bm.LockBits(new Rectangle(0,0,16,16), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bm.PixelFormat);
        IntPtr ptr = bitmapData.Scan0;

        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[16 * 16 * 3];

        int b = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < bm.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bm.Width; x++)
            {
                if (x < 7)
                {
                    rgbValues[b++] = 255; // BLUE, not red!
                    rgbValues[b++] = 0; // g
                    rgbValues[b++] = 0; // r
                }
                else
                {
                    rgbValues[b++] = 0; // r
                    rgbValues[b++] = 0; // g
                    rgbValues[b++] = 0; // b

                }
            }
        }

        int bytes = rgbValues.Length;
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);
        bm.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        pictureBox1.Image = bm;

    }
```

Also, note that the first byte you write should be the BLUE component, then green, then red.

Comment: ahhh, you actually revealed my problem after I tested this code; my width was the outerloop and height was the inner loop, so I had it the wrong way around. Really dumb. Thanks!